# will gtk4 apps run on ubuntu20.04

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I think Ubuntu22.04 is shipped with gtk4. But I could not find information about compatibility of gtk3/gtk4.

Does a gtk4 app run on a older OS that ships with gtk3? Does a gtk3 app run on Ubuntu22.04 that carries gtk4?

Assuming i am only depending on the system gtk lib.

Comment: If you're using a newer stack (eg. GTK4) you can run most older software (GTK3; parts of GTK3 are included), just as GTK3 could run older GTK2 software, however the reverse is less likely to be true.  The older the stack you have (GTK3 has many versions!), the less newer software you're able to run. Ubuntu releases come with a specific set of libraries/toolkits that everything works with, upgrading parts of that stack (*& not all*) risks making your system a *frakensystem* (*breaking your system, it may run in some ways but you'll need to fix/patch it yourself as auto tools may not work*)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with GTK4, but it also retains support for GTK3 applications

More specifically:

> Does a gtk4 app run on a older OS that ships with gtk3?

The app won't run if only GTK3 is available on the system because GTK4 brings too many changes that are not in GTK3.

> Does a gtk3 app run on Ubuntu 22.04 that has gtk4?

Yes, because both libraries are available on the system.